# Keyboard and Mouse interactions with and without build() method of Actions class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In order to perform mouse and keyboard actions, Selenium WebDriver has [Actions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class. Suppose if we want to double click an element, we'll have code like following  -

```
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.doubleClick(visibleElement).build().perform();
```

Same we can have without `build()` method like -

```
builder.doubleClick(visibleElement).perform()
```

For both, I saw same behaviour. Could you please help to understand how it impacts actions with and without `build()` method.

In existing tests, suppose I've actions without `build()` and now I use it or I have tests with `build()` and now I remove it, how will it affect test execution behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, all `perform()` does is calling `build().perform();`.

[Actions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java)

```
/**
* A convenience method for performing the actions without calling build() first.
*/
public void perform() {
    build().perform();
}
```

`build()` return private inner class `BuiltAction` which has its own `perform()`. This perform all the actions added to the actions list.

```
public Action build() {
    Action toReturn = new BuiltAction(driver, new LinkedHashMap<>(sequences), action);
    action = new CompositeAction();
    sequences.clear();
    return toReturn;
}

private static class BuiltAction implements Action {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
    if (driver == null) {
        // One of the deprecated constructors was used. Fall back to the old way for now.
        fallBack.perform();
        return;
    }

    try {
        ((Interactive) driver).perform(sequences.values());
    } catch (ClassCastException | UnsupportedCommandException e) {
        // Fall back to the old way of doing things. Old Skool #ftw
      fallBack.perform();
    }
}
```